# How do I get my JavaScript file to execute at the end of my component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can not get the imported javascript file to load after my html has loaded.

I have recently gotten into coding with react and I am very new at it. I am including a picture Gallery on my website. Whenever i run my code i recieve this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
```

As far as i have understood, it's because the imported 'homebasescript.js' is run first, and therefore has nothing to return.
How do i change the code to get it to work properly? I would be very thankful for any help!

#### Homebase.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Homebase.scss';
import Shuffle from 'shufflejs';
import Demo from './Homebasescript.js';


class homebase extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <section className="about-page">

      <div className="container-about">
        <div className="row-about">
          <div className="col-12@sm">
            <h1 className="about-title">Shuffle homepage demo</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="container-about">
        <div className="row-about">
          <div className="col-4@sm col-3@md">
            <div className="filters-group">
              <label htmlFor="filters-search-input" className="filter-label">Search</label>
              <input className="textfield filter__search js-shuffle-search" type="search" id="filters-search-input" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="row-about">
          <div className="col-12@sm filters-group-wrap">
            <div className="filters-group">
              <p className="filter-label">Filter</p>
              <div className="btn-group filter-options">
                <button className="btn btn--primary" data-group="space">Space</button>
                <button className="btn btn--primary" data-group="nature">Nature</button>
                <button className="btn btn--primary" data-group="animal">Animal</button>
                <button className="btn btn--primary" data-group="city">City</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <fieldset className="filters-group">
              <legend className="filter-label">Sort</legend>
              <div className="btn-group sort-options">
                <label className="btn active">
                  <input type="radio" name="sort-value" value="dom" defaultChecked /> Default
                </label>
                <label className="btn">
                  <input type="radio" name="sort-value" value="title" /> Title
                </label>
                <label className="btn">
                  <input type="radio" name="sort-value" value="date-created" /> Date Created
                </label>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="container-about">
        <div id="grid" className="row-about my-shuffle-container-about">
          <div className="col-1@sm col-1@xs my-sizer-element"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      </section>

    );
  };
};

export default homebase;
```

#### Homebasescript.js

```
import Shuffle from 'shufflejs';

class Demo {
  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.shuffle = new Shuffle(element, {
      itemSelector: '.picture-item',
      sizer: element.querySelector('.my-sizer-element'),
    });

    // Log events.
    this.addShuffleEventListeners();
    this._activeFilters = [];
    this.addFilterButtons();
    this.addSorting();
    this.addSearchFilter();
  }

  /**
   * Shuffle uses the CustomEvent constructor to dispatch events. You can listen
   * for them like you normally would (with jQuery for example).
   */
  addShuffleEventListeners() {
    this.shuffle.on(Shuffle.EventType.LAYOUT, (data) => {
      console.log('layout. data:', data);
    });
    this.shuffle.on(Shuffle.EventType.REMOVED, (data) => {
      console.log('removed. data:', data);
    });
  }

  addFilterButtons() {
    const options = document.querySelector('.filter-options');
    if (!options) {
      return;
    }

    const filterButtons = Array.from(options.children);
    const onClick = this._handleFilterClick.bind(this);
    filterButtons.forEach((button) => {
      button.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
    });
  }

  _handleFilterClick(evt) {
    const btn = evt.currentTarget;
    const isActive = btn.classList.contains('active');
    const btnGroup = btn.getAttribute('data-group');

    this._removeActiveClassFromChildren(btn.parentNode);

    let filterGroup;
    if (isActive) {
      btn.classList.remove('active');
      filterGroup = Shuffle.ALL_ITEMS;
    } else {
      btn.classList.add('active');
      filterGroup = btnGroup;
    }

    this.shuffle.filter(filterGroup);
  }

  _removeActiveClassFromChildren(parent) {
    const { children } = parent;
    for (let i = children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      children[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
  }

  addSorting() {
    const buttonGroup = document.querySelector('.sort-options');
    if (!buttonGroup) {
      return;
    }
    buttonGroup.addEventListener('change', this._handleSortChange.bind(this));
  }

  _handleSortChange(evt) {
    // Add and remove `active` class from buttons.
    const buttons = Array.from(evt.currentTarget.children);
    buttons.forEach((button) => {
      if (button.querySelector('input').value === evt.target.value) {
        button.classList.add('active');
      } else {
        button.classList.remove('active');
      }
    });

    // Create the sort options to give to Shuffle.
    const { value } = evt.target;
    let options = {};

    function sortByDate(element) {
      return element.getAttribute('data-created');
    }

    function sortByTitle(element) {
      return element.getAttribute('data-title').toLowerCase();
    }

    if (value === 'date-created') {
      options = {
        reverse: true,
        by: sortByDate,
      };
    } else if (value === 'title') {
      options = {
        by: sortByTitle,
      };
    }
    this.shuffle.sort(options);
  }

  // Advanced filtering
  addSearchFilter() {
    const searchInput = document.querySelector('.js-shuffle-search');
    if (!searchInput) {
      return;
    }
    searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', this._handleSearchKeyup.bind(this));
  }

  /**
   * Filter the shuffle instance by items with a title that matches the search input.
   * @param {Event} evt Event object.
   */
  _handleSearchKeyup(evt) {
    const searchText = evt.target.value.toLowerCase();
    this.shuffle.filter((element, shuffle) => {
      // If there is a current filter applied, ignore elements that don't match it.
      if (shuffle.group !== Shuffle.ALL_ITEMS) {
        // Get the item's groups.
        const groups = JSON.parse(element.getAttribute('data-groups'));
        const isElementInCurrentGroup = groups.indexOf(shuffle.group) !== -1;
        // Only search elements in the current group
        if (!isElementInCurrentGroup) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      const titleElement = element.querySelector('.picture-item__title');
      const titleText = titleElement.textContent.toLowerCase().trim();
      return titleText.indexOf(searchText) !== -1;
    });
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  window.demo = new Demo(document.getElementById('grid'));
});
```

The error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
```

is appearing in my 'Homebasescript.js'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah it looks like the issue is in attempting create a new `Demo` instance in the `DOMContentLoaded` event listener. This event will not consider the rendering of all your React components, only the initial load of your actual HTML (which might be very basic, e.g. a single `div`). Thus, the element with id `"grid"` won't have rendered after the `DOMContentLoaded` is triggered, which is why that element comes out as `null`.

The recommended way to create pretty much anything inside a React project is to do so within other components. You could move the creation of the `Demo` instance to within a lifecycle method of your `homebase` class. However, it looks like you're rendering some HTML inside of the `homebase` class and then using the `Demo` class to directly modify the DOM to change that HTML.

A better way would be to have `Demo` be a React component as well and to have it render that `div` with the id `"grid"`. This method of directly manipulating the DOM is sort of the older, jQuery style of rendering, and with React you can use JavaScript to decide what things to render ahead of time—rather than rendering and then modifying. Also components can hold their own state internally rather than needing to store everything in CSS classes. All these features together make for much more readable code.

Basically you would have something like:

```js
class Homebase extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <section>
                { /* other elements */ }

                <div className="container-about">
                    <Demo/>
                </div>
            </section>
        )
    }
}

class Demo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pictures: [], // start them off empty, you can populate them later
        }
    }

    handleShuffleClick() {
        this.setState({pictures: shuffle(pictures)}); // where 'shuffle' is a function that shuffles
    }

    render() {
        const pictureElements = this.state.pictures.map(picture => (
            <Picture pictureData={ picture }/>
        ))

        return (
            <div id="grid" className="row-about my-shuffle-container-about">
                <div className="col-1@sm col-1@xs my-sizer-element">
                    <button onClick={ this.handleShuffleClick }>Shuffle!</button>

                    <div className="pictures-container">
                        { pictureElements }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Picture extends Component {
    render() {
        // define how each Picture element displays in HTML from given data (through this.props)
        return (
            <div>
                { this.props.pictureData.title }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

There's a lot to go over in the code you provided, but hopefully this example shows a bit of how you can control rendering in React. I'd really recommend going over the [intro docs](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html), they're pretty accessible and you'll learn a lot. Let me know if I can clarify anything in here!

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to reply in such detail! Your code is exactly what i need and the readability is so good! I am going to take some time and do my best rewriting my code into this format. And I am going to take some time reading through the intro docs to fully understand it! Thank you again!

Comment: @ArisProto for sure! React is definitely a different way of thinking about and doing things if you're used to the jQuery style. I'd say just start simple and you can build complexity slowly over time—and it helps to keep components as small as possible!